# Android Firebase Storage Example

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Firebase's example Storage app for testing purposes. Unfortunately, it won't work for me. I have tried countless things to no avail.

My error is listed below as well. I understand it is telling me there is no such file or directory but I can't seem to figure that why. Also I did confirm I have read/write privileges for external storage

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage

MainActivity.java

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;

import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener, EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "Storage#MainActivity";

    private static final int RC_TAKE_PICTURE = 101;
    private static final int RC_STORAGE_PERMS = 102;

    private static final String KEY_FILE_URI = "key_file_uri";
    private static final String KEY_DOWNLOAD_URL = "key_download_url";

    private BroadcastReceiver mDownloadReceiver;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private Uri mDownloadUrl = null;
    private Uri mFileUri = null;

    // [START declare_ref]
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    // [END declare_ref]

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Initialize Firebase Storage Ref
        // [START get_storage_ref]
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        // [END get_storage_ref]

        // Click listeners
        findViewById(R.id.button_camera).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_download).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Restore instance state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mFileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_FILE_URI);
            mDownloadUrl = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_DOWNLOAD_URL);
        }

        // Download receiver
        mDownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "downloadReceiver:onReceive:" + intent);
                hideProgressDialog();

                if (MyDownloadService.ACTION_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    String path = intent.getStringExtra(MyDownloadService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
                    long numBytes = intent.getLongExtra(MyDownloadService.EXTRA_BYTES_DOWNLOADED, 0);

                    // Alert success
                    showMessageDialog("Success", String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                            "%d bytes downloaded from %s", numBytes, path));
                }

                if (MyDownloadService.ACTION_ERROR.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    String path = intent.getStringExtra(MyDownloadService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PATH);

                    // Alert failure
                    showMessageDialog("Error", String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                            "Failed to download from %s", path));
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());

        // Register download receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .registerReceiver(mDownloadReceiver, MyDownloadService.getIntentFilter());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Unregister download receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mDownloadReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
        out.putParcelable(KEY_FILE_URI, mFileUri);
        out.putParcelable(KEY_DOWNLOAD_URL, mDownloadUrl);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);
        if (requestCode == RC_TAKE_PICTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (mFileUri != null) {
                    uploadFromUri(mFileUri);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "File URI is null");
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Taking picture failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    // [START upload_from_uri]
    private void uploadFromUri(Uri fileUri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:src:" + fileUri.toString());

        // [START get_child_ref]
        // Get a reference to store file at photos/<FILENAME>.jpg
        final StorageReference photoRef = mStorageRef.child("photos")
                .child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
        // [END get_child_ref]

        // Upload file to Firebase Storage
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        showProgressDialog();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:dst:" + photoRef.getPath());
        photoRef.putFile(fileUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Upload succeeded
                        Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:onSuccess");

                        // Get the public download URL
                        mDownloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Upload failed
                        Log.w(TAG, "uploadFromUri:onFailure", exception);

                        mDownloadUrl = null;

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: upload failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END upload_from_uri]

    @AfterPermissionGranted(RC_STORAGE_PERMS)
    private void launchCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "launchCamera");

        // Check that we have permission to read images from external storage.
        String perm = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perm)) {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.rationale_storage),
                    RC_STORAGE_PERMS, perm);
            return;
        }

        // Choose file storage location, must be listed in res/xml/file_paths.xml
        File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(externalDir, "photos/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

        // Create content:// URI for file, required since Android N
        // See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html
        mFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                "com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.fileprovider", file);

        // Create and launch the intent
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RC_TAKE_PICTURE);
    }

    private void signInAnonymously() {
        // Sign in anonymously. Authentication is required to read or write from Firebase Storage.
        showProgressDialog();
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:SUCCESS");
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        updateUI(authResult.getUser());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "signInAnonymously:FAILURE", exception);
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void beginDownload() {
        // Get path
        String path = "photos/" + mFileUri.getLastPathSegment();

        // Kick off download service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyDownloadService.class);
        intent.setAction(MyDownloadService.ACTION_DOWNLOAD);
        intent.putExtra(MyDownloadService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PATH, path);
        startService(intent);

        // Show loading spinner
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        // Signed in or Signed out
        if (user != null) {
            findViewById(R.id.layout_signin).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.layout_storage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.layout_signin).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.layout_storage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Download URL and Download button
        if (mDownloadUrl != null) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_download_uri))
                    .setText(mDownloadUrl.toString());
            findViewById(R.id.layout_download).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.picture_download_uri))
                    .setText(null);
            findViewById(R.id.layout_download).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void showMessageDialog(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .create();
        ad.show();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_camera:
                isExternalStorageWritable();
                launchCamera();
                break;
            case R.id.button_sign_in:
                signInAnonymously();
                break;
            case R.id.button_download:
                beginDownload();
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CAN READ AND WRITE",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "YOU CANNOT!!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {}

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {}
}
```

My Error I get is the following:

```
07-23 03:15:57.006 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage D/Storage#MainActivity: uploadFromUri:src:content://com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.fileprovider/external/4b68b0e9-c950-4cf1-bee3-2bedfcda52dd.jpg
    07-23 03:15:57.086 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage D/Storage#MainActivity: uploadFromUri:dst:/photos/4b68b0e9-c950-4cf1-bee3-2bedfcda52dd.jpg
    07-23 03:15:57.116 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage W/UploadTask: could not retrieve file size for upload content://com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.fileprovider/external/4b68b0e9-c950-4cf1-bee3-2bedfcda52dd.jpg
    07-23 03:15:57.116 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage E/UploadTask: could not locate file for uploading:content://com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.fileprovider/external/4b68b0e9-c950-4cf1-bee3-2bedfcda52dd.jpg
    07-23 03:15:57.126 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
          An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
           Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
    07-23 03:15:57.126 23429-23429/com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage E/StorageException: No such file or directory
      java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
          at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
          at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
          at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
          at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.openFile(FileProvider.java:522)
          at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1336)
          at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1516)
          at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1582)
          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:393)
          at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1088)
          at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:927)
          at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:652)
          at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
          at com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.MainActivity$override.uploadFromUri(MainActivity.java:186)
          at com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.MainActivity$override.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:161)
          at com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
          at com.google.firebase.quickstart.firebasestorage.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:0)
          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4054)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3380)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3425)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4462)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:177)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1454)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Please make your code a bit more concise to get a better answer to your question.

Comment: This is the exact code in the firebase storage github

Comment: Hi @CirqueM. Within the uploadFromUri method I created a new File from the fileUri and my code worked. e.g:

Uri uploadUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUri.toString()));

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new File and pass fileUri.toString() as parameter:

```
Uri uploadUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUri.toString()));
```

Here is one that works:

```
// [START upload_from_uri]
private void uploadFromUri(Uri fileUri) {

    Uri uploadUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileUri.toString()));

    Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:src:" + fileUri.toString());

    // [START get_child_ref]
    // Get a reference to store file at photos/<FILENAME>.jpg
    final StorageReference photoRef = mStorageRef.child("photos").child(uploadUri.getLastPathSegment());
    // [END get_child_ref]

    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:dst:" + photoRef.getPath());

    photoRef.putFile(uploadUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Upload succeeded
                    Log.d(TAG, "uploadFromUri:onSuccess");

                    // Get the public download URL
                    mDownloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Upload failed
                    Log.w(TAG, "uploadFromUri:onFailure", exception);

                    mDownloadUrl = null;

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: upload failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END upload_from_uri]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is well clear:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

if you are try open a image from galery to send the FirebaseStorage. Verify your Uri if is true.